# Optional / on end of an URL

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I found out, today that its not the same if i open my URL with / on end or not for the rewrite rule.

```
# Pokedex
rewrite (?i)^\/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex\/$            /i.php?p=pokedex last;
rewrite (?i)^\/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex\/+([A-Za-z0-9]+)$     /i.php?p=pokedex&pokemon=$1 last;
```

If i open now `domain.com/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex/` everything works. But `domain.com/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex` doesnt. Now i search a way, to make the / optional.

What i tryed (but failed by the nginx-config-test)

```
rewrite (?i)^\/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex+([\/]){0,1}$
rewrite (?i)^\/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex+([\/]{0,1})$
```

On RegExr.com this (//Pokemon-Go-Pokedex+[/]{0,1}) works, bot not in the config, so i need help.

Comment: Thats exactly what im looking for. If you post it, as an answer i can confirm it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` make the previous character/group optional.

```
rewrite (?i)^\/Pokemon-Go-Pokedex\/?$
```